# Run console with Python application context (Like bundle exec console)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, uvicorn

In Ruby (bundler) we can run an IRB console with the application context loaded. This allows us to interact with the ORM, or other application objects.

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Python (i.e. uvicorn/fastapi/sqlalchemy)?

My goal is to interact with the ORM programatically from a console.

Comment: Anything you can do in a script, you can do from the Python console.  You can import your models and make requests just like an application.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sweet this was easy, thanks Tim! :D